# load json data to d3 dataset

Tags: json, d3.js

I have an array in a json data:

```
[5,3,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1]
```

I want to use this on d3 to make a chart. I tried doing

```
d3.json("data.json", function(error, data) {
            var dataset = data; 
        }
```

but when I declare the variable as

`[5,3,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1`]

it works.

How can I get this to use the data straight from the json file?

Comment: Do you get any errors? You have forgotten the closing parenthesis and semicolon for the d3.json method.

Comment: I fixed the missing ); but still nothing. When I view it on the console, it says no element selected. @Jonas

Comment: Can you please provide more code on how you're trying to create the chart?

Comment: Are you running this on a webserver? Or just directly from a browser on your computer? If the later it may be because you are doing a cross-domain JSON request